# A property type derived by multiple interfaces

Tags: c#

I can use generic methods and set the generic type to derive from multiple interfaces.
How do I set properties to have types that derive from multiple interfaces?

Otherwise, I am restricted to use explicit types that I cannot change.

```
public class FooBar
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Bar { get; } = new();
    
    // Property here with a type that uses multiple interfaces
    
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo(Bar);
    }

    public void Foo<T>(T collection) where T : ICollection<string>, INotifyCollectionChanged
    {
        collection.Add("bar");
        collection.CollectionChanged += Collection_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void Collection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, you need to make the declaring type itself generic, lifting the method constraints to constraints on the type parameter added to the declaring type. Ie `class FooBar<T> where T: ICollection<string>, INotifyCollectionChanged { public T Prop {get; set;} }`

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for [implicit interface](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/344#issuecomment-303846789)

Comment: Yes, that would be great but it's a different concept. That would introduce a veneer of structural typing into the language. Anyway I don't think we're going to see it anytime soon

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the property as `dynamic` (checking in the setter that the correct interfaces are implemented

```
public class FooBar
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Bar { get; } = new();


    private dynamic? _fooProp;  
    public dynamic? FooProp
    {
        get => _fooProp;
        set
        { 
           if (!(value is ICollection<string> && value is INotifyCollectionChanged ))
               throw new InvalidCastException();
           _fooProp = value;
        }
    }

    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo(Bar);
    }

    public void Foo<T>(T collection) where T : ICollection<string>, INotifyCollectionChanged 
    {
        FooProp = collection;
        collection.Add("bar");
        collection.CollectionChanged += Collection_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void Collection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Note: if it is an option to make the complete class generic, the approach suggested by Aluan Haddad in the comments seems to be a more elegant solution.